# Is Pylance working properly for Annotated Pydantic Fields?

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic, pylance

**Why does Pylance warn for Alice?**

I expect that field `seed` should be identical for both classes `User1` and `User2`.

```py
import random
from typing import Annotated

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

RandomInt = Annotated[int, Field(default_factory=lambda:random.randint(0, 1000))]


class User1(BaseModel):
    name : str
    seed : RandomInt


class User2(BaseModel):
    name : str
    seed : int = Field(default_factory=lambda: random.randint(0, 1000))


if __name__ == '__name__':
    alice = User1(name='Alice')

    bob = User2(name='Bob')
```

But instead Pylance warns

```
(variable) name: str
Argument missing for parameter "seed"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

Even though the code runs perfectly and the `default_factory` defined in `RandomInt` does its job.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

The usage in `User1.seed` and `User2.seed` is not equivalent. Pydantic's `Field` is *not* a type annotation, it must be used as a value (as is for `User2.seed`). Such, pydantic just interprets `User1.seed` as an `int` field, with no default value, and so requires you to provide a value on creation.

[`Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) is used for providing non-type annotations alongside type annotations (type annotations are the norm, but annotations can be used for another applications).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make sense to me. Note that the code above code executes just fine (when adding validate_assignment = True in config =). So So clearly Pylance warns for an error that does no happen.

Comment: As far as pylance/mypy is concerned, `my_var: Annotated[int, Field(...)]` and `my_var: int` are identical.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case, however for Python they are treated differently. That's why the code posted above does not crash. So Pylance is warning, for something that Python is accepting. The same code through Mypy without warnings as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is specific behavior from Pydantic which supports `default_factory`, but Python's type system doesn't know that Pydantic will generate a default value. To Python's type system (and thus Pylance) `RandomInt` is an annotated `int`, and Pylance (as well as MyPy and others) will ignore any annotations, since they're application-specific.

Note that `pydantic.Field()` is type-hinted itself as returning a value (I believe it's hinted as `Any`?), which is why Pylance won't give a warning about missing default value (because a default value exists) for `User2`, but warns about no default value in `User1`.